# Python Model Callbacks

Tags: python, callback, magic-methods

I'm trying to implement a simple model class that executes callbacks whenever an attribute is set in the class, however I am getting an AttributeError when trying to use this in my application. It seems the instance doesn't have the attributes I setup in my initializer and I'm a bit confused as to why. I haven't used magic methods much, so some elaboration might be helpful:

```
class ReportModel(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.current_date = None
        self.prior_date = None
        self._callbacks = defaultdict([])

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
        for func in self._callbacks[attr]:
            func(value)

    def set_callback(self, attr, function):
        self._callbacks[attr].append(function)
```

Traceback:

```
AttributeError: 'ReportModel' object has no attribute '_callbacks'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have overridden `__setattr__()`, when you do `self.current_date = None` in `__init__()` it will call your `__setattr__()` implementation which will try to access `self._callbacks`.  This is what causes the AttributeError.

Here is one option to fix this:

```
class ReportModel(object):

     def __init__(self):
         object.__setattr__(self, '_callbacks', defaultdict(list))
         self.current_date = None
         self.prior_date = None

     def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
         object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
         for func in self._callbacks[attr]:
             func(value)

     def set_callback(self, attr, function):
         self._callbacks[attr].append(function)
```

This adds the `_callbacks` attribute using `object.__setattr__()` before any other attributes are added, so that future calls to `__setattr__()` for your `ReportModel` instance will not choke on accessing `self._callbacks`.

Alternatively, you could modify `__setattr__()` to check for the existence of the `_callbacks` attribute:

```
class ReportModel(object):

     def __init__(self):
         object.__setattr__(self, '_callbacks', defaultdict(list))
         self.current_date = None
         self.prior_date = None

     def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
         object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
         if hasattr(self, '_callbacks'):
             for func in self._callbacks[attr]:
                 func(value)

     def set_callback(self, attr, function):
         self._callbacks[attr].append(function)
```

Comment: Tried your implementation, and I'm getting a TypeError:   File "C:\FAST\Workspace\FIMOApp\src\fimoapp\models.py", line 12, in __init__
    object.__setattr__(self, '_callbacks', defaultdict([]))
TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: Woops - its the defaultdict, apologies

Answer (score 2):

Your `__setattr__` method is called during the class instantiation when `__init__` is running and setting `self.current_date` and `self.prior_date`.

To fix this you have to use try, except block around callback calling to prevent the error.

```
    try:
        for func in self._callbacks[attr]:
            func(value)
    except:
        pass
```